# What is the equivalent of http_get in hhvm?

Tags: hhvm

I guess you can use file_get_contents, but is there something equivalent to http_get in hhvm? When I use google it points to hhvm docs which simply say it isn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions like this marked as missing in HHVM are usually because the function is part of an extension that hasn't been implemented yet. The [PHP.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php) say it's part of a PECL extension, `pecl_http` -- [which doesn't look to be on by default even in PHP5](http://3v4l.org/IaW05) (although of course it can be manually enabled). So definitely looks like the relevant extension hasn't been implemented in HHVM. If this function specifically is really important, and you can't find an adequate replacement, you can [file a feature request issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues) to let the team know you'd like it implemented. (Or send a pull request if you want to implement it yourself, of course!)

As for a replacement, I'd start with `file_get_contents`; if that doesn't meet your needs, I'm pretty sure [the curl extension exists in HHVM](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/book.curl.php). It's got a huge array of functionality, but you can almost certainly use it to do whatever you need.